# How do I add a variable to a phonegap plugin with Meteor?

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I have a plugin, https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin, that I would like to use with Meteor. I added the GIT repo to `app/.meteor/cordova-plugins`.

The plugin requires a variable to be passed to it when it's installed.  How would I add that variable?

I added this to `mobile-config.js`:

```
// Pass preferences for a particular PhoneGap/Cordova plugin
App.configurePlugin('nl.x-services.plugins.launchmyapp', {
  URL_SCHEME: 'mycoolapp'
});
App.setPreference("URL_SCHEME", "mycoolapp");
```

I am still getting the error that states that the variable URL_SCHEME is missing.

Comment: Can you try also setting a preference with `App.setPreference("URL_SCHEME", "mycoolapp")` and see if that works?

Comment: I've looked into it, and this is a bug that we just fixed and will come out in the next release. Thank you!

Comment: A Meteor bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I think your code is correct. It was a bug in Meteor that we just fixed on devel.

Comment: @imslavko which part of the code above?

Comment: the configurePlugin syntax is the right one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will post a complete answer in case someone stumbles on it.

From [Meteor Phonegap documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration):

> Some Cordova/Phonegap plugins, such as the "Facebook Connect" plugin, require build-time variables such as an APP_ID or APP_NAME. To include these variables in your Cordova/Phonegap build, set them up in your Mobile Configuration file (starting from 0.9.4). (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#cordova-plugins-configuration)

So if you look at the example, here is a way to do it in your app's `mobile-config.js` file:

`App.configurePlugin('org.apache.my-plugin', {
  variable: 'value'
});`

Comment: Is there a way to access those settings on server side from JS?

Comment: mobile-config.js can not be accessed from client or server.